# How can I modify this detail in the article ""Extending Multi-Sense Word Embedding to Phrases and Sentences for Unsupervised Semantic Applications"?"

Tags: neural-networks

This question is about de paper [Extending Multi-Sense Word Embedding to Phrases and Sentences
for Unsupervised Semantic Applications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.15330.pdf).

I am interested in the transformer part of the paper and the main structures of the algorithm is represented in the following image:

[image]

Before the main questions I have other questions which perharps will help the main question:

What is the role of the DECODER?
Why do I need a encoder/decoder?

Main question:

In the paper the authors replace the transformer encoder by an bi-LSTM and the transformer decoder with LSTM.

What are the other options for replacing the encoder/decoder part of the algorithm?
Is it possible to replace the encoder/decoder at once by a single structure?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for being interested in our work.

The role of the decoder is to model the dependency between the codebook embeddings. For example, in this case, outputting an embedding close to sings might be correlated to outputting an embedding close to microphone.

There are several reasons that we choose to use a seq2seq (encoder/decoder) architecture. For example, we want to compare with the related work such as skip-thought. In addition, the sentence length varies but we want to output a fixed number of embeddings.

If you want, you can input a fixed number of multiple special tokens into a transformer encoder and use the corresponding hidden states as the codebook embedding. We find that this encoder-only architecture is more likely to output almost identical embeddings (i.e., multiple embeddings collapse into a single embedding), especially when a transformer with many layters such as BERT. We are investigating some solutions to this problem now.